# Will JavaScript become much less important in near future?

Tags: javascript

I am a junior web developer and now I am also developing iOS and Android applications. I am just wondering if it is worthwhile to invest much time and energy in learning JavaScript and developing in JavaScript. I am not sure whether HTML 5 or CSS3 will totally replace JavaScript or creating cross-platform applications will not need JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: Please review this FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Short answer: "No". (Why would think HTML 5 and/or CSS3 would replace JavaScript?)

Comment: HTML5 is not referring to just HTML, it's a misconception, HTML5 represents the whole web 3.0 if you will, and that includes JavaScript. HTML5 as a markup language could never replace JavaScript as it is today and it probably won't in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put things in perspective, there are more JavaScript virtual machines deployed than any other VM technology.  Nearly every device that has a web browser is capable of executing JavaScript.

Due to this fact alone, it is unlikely that JavaScript will become "much less important."  If anything, its usage should continue to grow.

Answer (score 1):

Java script is always important in all cases.